# Router does not listen to useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Need your help. The project is translated into 3 languages by i18n and want when the language changes the one to appear in the url.

In the i18n gave high priority to local storage, so languages are kept there. The code is following for i18n

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

const languages = ["en",  "es", "ar"]



const options = {

    order: ['localStorage','cookie','path',  'querystring', 'sessionStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag', 'subdomain'],


    lookupQuerystring: 'lng',
    lookupCookie: 'i18next',
    lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    lookupSessionStorage: 'i18nextLng',
    lookupFromPathIndex: 0,
    lookupFromSubdomainIndex: 0,

    caches: [ 'localStorage', 'cookie', ],
    excludeCacheFor: ['cimode'],


    cookieMinutes: 10,
    cookieDomain: 'myDomain',

    htmlTag: document.documentElement,


    cookieOptions: { path: '/', sameSite: 'strict' }
}


i18n

    .use(Backend)

    .use(LanguageDetector)

    .use(initReactI18next)

    .init({
        fallbackLng: "ar",
        lng: 'en',
        debug: true,
        whitelist: languages,
        detection: options,

        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
        }
    });


export default i18n;
```

the function of getting language from the local storage is following

```
 const [langs, setlangs]=useState("")
 

 useEffect(() => {

       const language = localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng');

       if(language !== 0 ){
         setlangs(language)

       }

    }, [localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng'), langs]);
```

```
 Routers are following
```

```
<Menu.Item key="2" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
        <Link to={`/services/edit/${langs}`}>{props.t("SERVICES_EDIT_PAGE")}</Link>
 </Menu.Item>
 
and 

 <Route
        exact
        path="/services/edit/:langs"
        render={(routeProps) => {
          return (
            <MainLayout   >
              <ServicesEdit {...routeProps} />
            </MainLayout>
          );
        }}
      />
```

when the lang is logged it is working but in the url it is not changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent is to sync the value of `langs` to the currently set/detected language, you should instead make use of the `useTranslation` hook provided by `react-i18next`. To align with the naming convention of `i18next`, you should use `lng` instead of `langs`.

```js
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
// By default, this hook will trigger a render when `languageChanged` is fired
// `t()` is an alias for `i18n.t()`
// `i18n` is the active instance of i18next

const lng = i18n.language;
// This is the currently rendered language
// e.g. "en-US"

const lngs = i18n.languages;
// This is the "tree" of languages to search for translations
// e.g. ["en-US", "en", "fallbackLng1", "fallbackLng2", ...]

const supportedLngs = i18n.options.supportedLngs;
// The languages you defined in the call to `i18n.init()`
// NOTE: `options.whitelist` has been renamed to `options.supportedLngs`!
// e.g. ["en", "es", "ar"]
```

Because you are using externally sourced translation files using `i18next-http-backend`, you also need to make sure your main app component is wrapped in a [`Suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense) component so that it shows some form of loading screen while it fetches the translation maps. You could handle the [`ready` state manually](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense), but it's not worth doing.

In your `i18n` file, don't specify every detection option, only specify what you actively plan on using. For example, `order` should probably only include `['localStorage', 'querystring', 'navigator']` (which matches the user's saved preference, the given URL from a `?lng=` parameter and the browser's preference).

Using `?lng=` allows you to use the same URL path for each language which makes routing easier. You should consider which URL a user would prefer: `/dashboard/en` vs. `/dashboard?lng=en` (which will display as `/dashboard` in many browsers).

```
// i18n.js

import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

// renamed to match i18next's options
const supportedLngs = ['en', 'es', 'ar']

const detectionOptions = {
  order: ['localStorage', 'querystring', 'navigator'],

  lookupQuerystring: 'lng',         // if the url contains "?lng=", use that language
  lookupLocalStorage: 'i18nextLng', // if localStorage has a `i18nextLng` entry, use that language

  caches: ['localStorage'],
  excludeCacheFor: ['cimode']
};

const backendOptions = { /* ... */ };

i18n
    .use(Backend)           // use remote translation files
    .use(LanguageDetector)  // auto-detect language if possible
    .use(initReactI18next)  // use this instance for React components
    .init({
        lng: 'en',
        fallbackLng: 'ar',
        supportedLngs,      // NOTE: "whitelist" has been renamed to "supportedLngs"!

        debug: true,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
            // consider adding a `format: (value, format, lng) => string` method here for formatting things like Dates, numbers, etc. based on language
        }

        detection: detectionOptions,
        backend: backendOptions
    });

export default i18n;
```

```js
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

import './i18n';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```js
// App.js

import { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const App = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const lng = i18n.language;

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <Menu>
            {/* ... */}
            <Menu.Item key="2" icon={<UserOutlined />}>
              <Link to={`/services/edit/${lng}`}>
                {t("SERVICES_EDIT_PAGE")} 
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            {/* ... */}
          </Menu>
        </nav>

        <Switch>
          {/* ... */}
          <Route
            exact
            path="/services/edit/:lng"
            render={(routeProps) => {
              return (
                <MainLayout>
                  <ServicesEdit {...routeProps} />
                </MainLayout>
              );
            }}
          />
          {/* ... */}
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default function WrappedApp() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="...is loading"> {/* <-- you can put a component here */}
      <App />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

##### Further reading:

This [excellent blog post](https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb) by Adriano (one of `i18next`'s authors) covers how to use `react-i18next` quite well.

Comment: Changes are made .Now the problem is the language changes when the link is clicked for the second time.

Comment: @Diana You haven't yet shared how you are changing the language, what the language is being changed to, how you are handling links being clicked or which link being clicked is causing the problem.

Comment: The project is translated into 3 languages  arabic, spanish and  english. Did the same way as it is told. In the URL, languages are change but from the second click.When the title is clicked for the first time it is not changes in the URL , it is changes when i click second time, The code is the above one in the router =>  <Link to={`/services/edit/${lng}`}>

Comment: @Diana I don't see the call to `i18n.changeLanguage(newLanguage)` anywhere

Comment: it is passed in the dropdownmenu via props where the languages are defined.

 <Menu.Item>
                <a onClick={() => props.handleClick("en")} >
                    <div>
                        <span className="flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span>
                        English
                    </div>
                </a>
            </Menu.Item>


___ let handleClick = (lang) => {

        i18n.changeLanguage(lang)
    }

Answer (score -1):

you can do something like this:

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const router= useHistory();

<Menu.Item key="2" 
 icon={<UserOutlined />} 
 onClick={()=>router.push(`/services/edit/${langs}`)}
>
{props.t("SERVICES_EDIT_PAGE")}
 </Menu.Item>
```